# Where are Flurry event logs?

Tags: flurry

Flurry docs say that I should check the Event log when testing events. Where is the event log? The events menu is the only one without a submenu.

[image: Flurry menu]

Answer (score 0):

If you have completed a Flurry session on a test device the event log should populate within an hour or so. Be sure to close the app with the home button or relaunch the app once more to guarantee the session is sent.

If the problem persists add these lines of code before you start the Flurry session:

Android
FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true) ;
FlurryAgent.setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE) ;

iOS
[Flurry setDebugLogEnabled:YES]; 
[Flurry setLogLevel:FlurryLogLevelAll];

Look for a 200 response from our server when the session ends. Make sure you are using the latest SDK Android v5.5 or iOS v6.4

Comment: LogCat says Analytics report sent. My question was where is the event log. Where should I click to see the event log as described on this page https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/lexicon/eventreporting/ ?

Comment: It will appear in there when the session reports after about an hour.

Comment: Thanks, I'll wait and see.

Comment: Still waiting, Flurry still reporting 0 users, 0 sessions, 0 events. If it takes two hours or more to test every change I make in my app, it could take me days to integrate Flurry. Is this really how it works?

Comment: Please send your api key to support@flurry.com and we will dig into it. Please include the cat log showing the 200 response if possible. We'll be here for about three more hours before the long weekend.

Comment: Done. Although my app won't be published for another month at least, so I guess it can wait till after the weekend :)